# Cisco ACL for NTP

Tags: cisco, firewall, network-core, acl, ntp

We have Cisco ACL configured for all inbound traffic and today i have add NTP to allow few remote NTP server to sync tim.

I have created `object-group NTP` group and multiple remote NTP server in that group.

This is my ACL

```
permit udp object-group NTP any eq ntp
```

and ACL is applied on inbound interface of router but still my client not able to sync time.

```
[root@client1 ~]# ntpdate -u xx.xx.xx.xx
14 Aug 11:08:12 ntpdate[43243]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

```
permit udp object-group NTP eq ntp any
```